# How to resize the font size in a longtblr (tabularray)?

Tags: fontsize, tabularray, longtblr

The following `longtblr` table code and myself have some differences of opinion. For instance, the font size, which I would like to be 10pt, but the output just puts "10pt" above the table and then goes on to do what it wants to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrTheme{mytable}{
  %\SetTblrStyle{head}{bg=teal7}
  \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{normal}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
  \SetTblrStyle{caption-sep}{normal}{\enskip\(|\)\enskip}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = mytable,
    caption = A very long table,
    font=10pt,
  ]{
    colspec = {X[l,2cm] m{7cm} Q[c] Q[c]}, 
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    row{1} = {teal7},
  }
      \hline[1.5pt]
      column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
      \hline
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows centred in two \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
      row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & \SetCell[r=2]{c} rows \\
      row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
}
```

Any thoughts?

---

Edited to reduce the errors in the example. However, it appears I have misunderstood the package documentation. To me, it appears as though the colours and font command are loaded with the package, while the first commenter has told me to fix those. Also, it appears as though it's not really `\linewidth`.

Comment: I'm getting multiple syntax error messages: 1) the misplaced `}` at the end, 2) `\DefTblrStyle`  isn't defined, 3) `font` option isn't defined, 4) and after that other errors about colors… Can you first provide a correct example? After that, the `font` option is normally used as an argument to the `cell` or `cells` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considered @Miyase an @CarLaTeX comments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin= 3.5cm,
            vmargin={2cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewTblrTheme{mytable}{
  \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot,middlefoot}{\footnotesize\itshape}
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{\enskip\(|\)\enskip}
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-3]

\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = mytable,
caption = {A very long table},
  label = {tab:long...}
                ]{colspec = {l X[j, m] c c},
                  cells   = {font = \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont},
                  row{1}  = {teal9},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
    \toprule
column 1 & column 2 & column 3  & column 4 \\
    \midrule
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
row      & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
                    & row       & rows \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\kant[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I slightly streamlined and definitely cleaned your code from errors. If you are going to customise `longtblr`, you should read the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), mostly the part related to `longtblr`. It's not so easy to understand at first but makes sense once you have got the idea how themes and custom styles work.

I didn't understand the problem with font size because `10pt` is the default one in regular documents. However, it's possible to set a specific font size for you table, even though document is set to let's say `12pt` (see example). Make sure you put table with `\fontsize` in a group, so it affects only the table.

Here's a working code you can take from. I added a few paragraphs of dummy texts to compare the table with regular content.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewTblrTheme{mytable}{
  \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot,middlefoot}{\footnotesize\itshape}
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{\enskip\(|\)\enskip}
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]

\begingroup
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = mytable,
    caption = {A very long table},
  ]{
    colspec = {X[l] Q[7cm,m] Q[c] Q[c]}, 
    width = \linewidth,
    row{1} = {teal7},
    hline{1,Z} = {wd=1.5pt},
    hline{2} = {},
    cell{even[2-Z]}{4} = {r=2}{},
    rowhead = 1,
  }
  column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
  row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness & row & rows \\
  row & less showboating, maybe even no showboating & row & \\
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tabularray` has the `font=` option (you can use it in `rows=`, for example) no need to use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that in [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682375/31283)'s answer. I didn't realise we could also use `\fontsize` in cell settings. I'll leave code as is since Zarko provided code with the preferred approach.