# Tabularray - resize text in rows of longtblr without resizing caption text

Tags: fontsize, tabularray, longtblr

I need to insert a 2 columns long table in my document with a large amount of text on each cell of the second column. However, the final result has been a table covering 6 pages of the document.

I have been trying to reduce the fontsize of the text inside the table, but so far, the only solution I found resulted in reducing the size of the table's caption as well, which looked weird.

One of the solutions I tried is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682357/how-to-resize-the-font-size-in-a-longtblr-tabularray), but for some reason, I couldn't understand, it didn't work as expected.

For now, the solution I'm using is to insert the `longtblr` environment inside `\begingroup`, and then set the fontsize of the text there.

Is there a way to resize the text only in the cells, or some specific rows, keeping the original fontsize of the caption?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\begingroup
\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption of the table.},
label = {tab:label},
]{
    Q[c,m]|X[l,m]
}
\hline
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Answers on question in the given link do exactly what you require in your question title.
- If you have problems, how used solutions for table works, please read `tabularray` package or ask here, which part of code (presumably settings in table preamble) you have problems.
- A background and purpose of your table is unknown, but any kind of tables usually contain column headers, which are in cases of long table repeated on each pages spanned by it.
- From typographical point of view is recommended that whole table body has the same font size (for which is recommended, that table is srill readable, not to be smaller than `\footnoteseize`).
- If the table which use the proposed solutions in given link not sufficiently reduce table size, you still have two options to squize it a wee bit:

  - reduce `rowsep`, for example by setting `rowsep = 1pt` or `rowsep = 0.5pt`
  - reduce `\baselineskip` in cell texts, for example with `cells = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}`
- See, if the following solution (which to my opinion has more "professional" look) is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}              % added for better spacing of text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot,middlefoot}{\footnotesize\itshape}  

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption of the table.},
label = {tab:label},
                ]{colspec = {Q[c] X[j]},
                  cells   = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                  rowsep  = 1pt,
                  rowhead = 1
                 }
    \toprule
item    &   Description \\
    \midrule
row & \lipsum[66]   \\
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness\\
row & \lipsum[1]   \\
row & \lipsum[2]   \\
row & \lipsum[3]   \\
row & \lipsum[4]   \\
row & \lipsum[5]   \\
row & \lipsum[7]   \\
row & \lipsum[66]  \\
row & \lipsum[66]  \\
row & \lipsum[66]  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you prefer to have more ugly solution, which has smaller font size only in the  particular cells, than follow proposition in other answer, i.e. set font size for this cell locally by inserting in those cells

```
\SetCell{font=\tiny} % or any other font size
```

Off-topic: in any kind of table rows should be terminated accordingly. In your case at end of each row you should add `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

On the MWE there is a little mistake at the end of each row that makes compiling the document look a bit off. For `tabularray`, all rows have to end with `\\`, so this.

```latex
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness
```

Should be like this!

```latex
row & some relatively long description so that the other entries can showboat their floatiness \\
```

Now, I’m assuming that’s not the case in your real document. To force a particular column width on your columns, you only need to add the `wd` specification when using the `Q` column macros, so, in this example, line 18 should look like this:

```latex
  colspec = {Q[c,m]|Q[l,m,wd=10cm]}
```

The `colspec` command is just to tell the package that this should only affect the column setup, it’s good to put it like that since later you may need to edit other stuff in that field that will not affect columns. The “`wd`” option forces the cells of that column to use that value as the maximum text box width, so feel free to change it as you like! Also, as you were asking, you can control a column font size via the `Q` macro using the `font` option, like this:

```latex
  colspec={Q[c,m]|Q[l,m,wd=10cm,font=\tiny]}
```

Which makes the text on that column tiny! Of course you can do that via `\SetCell` inside the content to affect only one cell, but that’s up to you.

Testing a more with the document, I think that the only error was the lack of `\\` on the rows, but hopefully that extra bit of info helps you to add more flavor to what you are cooking! Hope that helps a bit!